# What are the disadvantages to the site owner to have third parties e-mails displayed publicly?

Tags: email, spam

I frequently have to remind my members not to post their e-mails due to spam bots. One of them told me he doesn't care about that since his spam filter is good enough. If I allow him to do that, are there disadvantages to my website?

Answer (score 2):

**A small one.**

Some spammers grab email address and domains to forge From: addresses.  If this user's email is public, that might increase the odds that a spammer will forge with it, pretending to be sending email from your domain even though the spam is actually coming from someplace else.  In which case, you might notice a slight uptick in warning notices to your maildaemon account, undeliverable email and the like.  I presume you already receive a high volume of these warnings and are already filtering them appropriately.

Other than that, I can't imagine any possible downsides.

Further, the user is right, if you have a good spam filter and know enough not to fall for a phishing attack, the risk of publishing your email address are minimal.

Answer (score 0):

E-mail address is not only an e-mail box. In many cases it's also:

- login name
- password retrieval channel

And user login names enumeration is a threat.

Comment: Excuse me but that doesn't answer the question.